# Embed chromium in flutter

Tags: flutter, chromium

I have a client with a web app wrapper that needs to work on old android devices.
The thing is, these android devices are so old they don’t have chrome.
Today we solve this my using a Xamarin wrapper that has an embedded chromium version. We’d like to move to flutter though.

Is there are way to use an embedded chromium version as the web view in Flutter?

Comment: did you figure this out ? im looking to do the same myself

Comment: @Sandeep we never did sadly, the strategy was changed before we spent too much time on it.

Comment: @Sandeep: I was researching on this and I believe you can using this package. You can even send events from the web page to Flutter and back which is pretty cool. 

https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter_plus/example

Comment: @StellanLindell thanks for this ! it looks pretty cool

Comment: @StellanLindell That's awesome! Could you rewrite as an answer pls?

Comment: @JesperBylund: Done. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was researching on this and I believe you can using this package. You can even send events from the web page to Flutter and back which is pretty cool. [pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter_plus/example](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter_plus/example)

Comment: This looks like it’s just the standard web view, not chromium?